# Random TransformerException, how to solve it?

Tags: java, xml, exception, random

My app writes a lot of XML data, and randomly the last line of the following piece of code:

```
// Prepare the DOM document for writing
Source source = new DOMSource(node);

// Prepare the output stream
Result result = new StreamResult(stream);

// Write the DOM document to the file
Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
xformer.transform(source, result);
```

..throws..

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.IOException: Detected invalid substitute UTF-16: da89 4f ?
```

(additionally, I don't know why, but this exception is the only one raised by the vm in my language, Portuguese, as "Detectado substituto UTF-16 inválido", I've translated it to "Detected invalid UTF-16 substitute")

Another strange thing is that I'm using UTF-8, not UTF-16, in my texts, I've checked it. And, I believe if the UTF was the problem, it would not cause randomly exception, as I'm getting the same amount of text to transform to XML.

This exception is difficult to reproduce, as it does not occur always, and it occurs when transforming lots of data to XML.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: So does it not even happen repeatedly if you transform the same document multiple times?

Comment: utf-16 is used internally by java, a char is also an unsigned 16bit int.

Somewhere in your source there must be a character that does not have a surrogate for it.

Also Java 1.4 uses version 3.0 of the Unicode standard, 1.3 uses version 2.1. These version generally don't support supplementary characters. Since 1.5 it should be supported then version 4 is used.

And do you generate the source in your app or is it from external files?

Comment: I was having a similar issue (although different error) every time I started my app. from console (shell script), but no problems when I launched it from Eclipse.

Are you starting the app. the same way every time?

Comment: @Rediab I'm using Java 6, the source code is in my app, the source text to transform into xml is a external file (I'm using always the same in the tests).

Comment: @FedericoCristina I'm always running it from Eclipse.

Comment: Does your program use multiple threads? Could it be that the source node is modified concurrently?

Comment: Do you read your text files as utf-8? If not java might assume that they are utf-16. When it later encounters an utf-8 character encoding which is invalid for utf-16 it throws the exception.

Comment: @Jörn not, everything is running on EDT.

Comment: @josefx if were this the problem, the error would happen always, as I'm using the same input text, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I could think is make the program re-excute the action when it fails. As it is difficult to reproduce, it should never occur twice in a row.

Comment: Have you been logging all the times when it fails? If not, you should setup a logger to log when it fails and what the xml data looks like that it fails on. You can then compare that to the working ones.

Comment: @xil3 good point. For me, as I was using the same input, looks like there is no difference, but yours may be a good idea.. there must be any difference somewhere.. Anyway, I'm no more working on that project.. so it stays with this workaround as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Construct your source from an input stream, not a reader, and let the XML parser figure out the character set.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, I updated my source code in the question. As you can see, I'm constructing the source using DMOSource(Node). If you mean the text source file, it is being contructed using an input stream.